# Sort / Uniq pipethrough usage

Tags: regex, sorting, awk, grep, uniq

So I'm trying to grep through an HTTP error log, take out all of the IPs in the result and then sort them, so that they're shown in order of the total amount of matches (ignoring any 'single' matches) so that I know which IPs to block.

My command thus far:

```
grep "File does not exist" local1.log | awk '{print $13;}' | sort -g | uniq -c | sort -n -k 1,1
```

My output from said command:

```
   5599 200.71.211.187]
   6439 91.102.160.191]
  10448 84.92.84.166]
  14181 27.159.226.198]
  20170 93.90.177.167]
```

Now I have a feeling that I'm doing too many pipethroughs and some kind of bastardised usage of uniq/sort....

My previous attempt was:

```
grep "File does not exist" local1.log | awk '{print $13;}' | uniq -dc | sort -n -k 1,1
```

Which gave me duplicate outputs from uniq, then sorted by total 'matches' from sort.

TL;DR:

There must be a more... eleqant way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, any suggestions? ^^

Edit -sort -u gives me a garbage list of IPs with single matches like:

```
  1 99.92.71.147]
  1 99.92.86.7]
  1 99.93.12.115]
  1 99.9.4.241]
  1 99.95.215.81]
  1 99.95.96.7]
  1 99.99.113.194]
  1 99.99.185.1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '/File does not exist/{count[$13]++}END{for(ip in count) print count[ip],ip}' local1.log
```

What we do here is create an array storing ip addresses as key and keep incrementing it. In the `END` block, we iterate over the array and print the number of times we see the ip and the ip itself.

You will probably have to pipe this to sort to get the output in sorted by count.

Comment: @nom Great, glad I could help. I must say as a new comer to this website, you did an excellent job in posting your question. You showed your attempt and a drive to better your attempt. You displayed your desired output and explored the possibility of answers that might not have worked for you. `+1` to your question. Good luck!